# SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, 'Authentication failed: account disabled') Python app

Tags: python, django, heroku, sendgrid

My Python app using sendgird account on Heroku to send email for user when they forgot password or login by link.
Problem is the sendgrid account, after 1-2 month using get disable, and I must change to new account.

Full log:

> Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "user_profile/services/profile.py", line 595, in send_mail_with_perm
>   msg.send(fail_silently=fail_silently)
>   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 292, in send
>   return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
>   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/email_log/backends.py", line 27, in send_messages
>   num_sent += message.send()
>   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 292, in send
>   return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
>   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 100, in send_messages
>   new_conn_created = self.open()
>   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 67, in open
>   self.connection.login(self.username, self.password)
>   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 623, in login
>   raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
>   SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, 'Authentication failed: account disabled')

Anyone get same problem ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because account troubles with a service provider are no programming problems.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely you have a [trial subscription](https://sendgrid.com/policies/tos/#trial), which will be cancelled if you don't sign up for an actual account (one tier is free but likely requires you to provide payment information anyway). Either that or you're repeatedly violating their terms of service/user agreement.

Comment: Thanks, I checked my account, look like the others testing on free account, so they hit limited email of sendgrid and account has been banned. I just replace payed account and everything seem good now.